# CakePHP - how to insert new line / line break in Html helper hyperlink

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

Using the CakePHP Html helper, how does one go about inserting a line break in the anchor text?

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link("My Anchor Text \n with new line", '/mycontroller/myaction'); ?>
```

The above doesn't work.

Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `br` tag for this purpose:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link("My Anchor Text <br /> with new line", '/mycontroller/myaction', array('escape' => false)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that and it showed up as the literal string "My Anchor Text <br /> with new line".

Comment: it's because you forgot this: array('escape' => false)

Comment: Ah.  I didn't use the scroller!  Thanks kaklon for pointing that out, and thanks dhofstet for the answer.